# CasperJS: How to fill a asp form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to automate a few steps of a asp written website through casperjs. I want to acheive following.

1. Navigate to the login page
2. Fill the username and password fields
3. click the login button
4. capture a screenshot of the success page

But so far I'm only able to do the first step in the process. The source view page looks little wired for me. Most of the nodes are starting with a `<ui:>` tag and I have no idea about it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="theme/xslt/all.xsl?build=2.0.012&amp;theme=theme_immi" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]> 
<ui:root title="ImmiAccount - Login" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://www.immi.gov.au/Namespace/UI/V1.0">
```

I first tried `fillSelectors()` method to submit form.

```
casper.start('https://online.immi.gov.au/lusc/login',function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());

    this.fillSelectors('#app_L2',{
        'input[id="app_L2b0a0a0a3a1a"]':  'john',
        'input[id="app_L2b0a0a0a3b1a"]':  'john123'
    });

    this.wait('2000',function(){
        this.capture('formfill.png');
    });    
});

casper.then(function() {
    // Click on 1st result link
    this.click('#app_L2b0a0a0a4a');
    this.wait('5000',function(){
        this.capture('success.png');
    })
});
```

got following error

```
CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: no field matching css selector "input[id="app_L2b0a0a0a3a1a"]" in form; 
no field matching css selector "input[id="app_L2b0a0a0a3b1a"]" in form
```

Then tried with `fillXPath()`

```
casper.start('https://online.immi.gov.au/lusc/login',function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());

    this.fillXPath('#app_L2',{
        '//*[@id="app_L2b0a0a0a3a1a"]':    'john',
        '//*[@id="app_L2b0a0a0a3b1a"]':  'john123'
    });

    this.wait('2000',function(){
        this.capture('formfill.png');
    });    
});

casper.then(function() {
    // Click on 1st result link
    this.click(x('//*[@id="app_L2b0a0a0a4a"]'),
    this.wait('5000',function(){
        this.capture('success.png');
    }));
});
```

Following erro occured

```
CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: Unable to find field element in form: FieldNotFound: Invalid field type; only HTMLElement and NodeList are supported; Unable to find field element in form: FieldNotFound: Invalid field type; only HTMLElement and NodeList are supported
```

And finally, I tried `sendkeys()` method to fill the fields and `click()` to hit the login button. Again, didn't find success. Here the code doing that

```
this.sendKeys('#app_L2b0a0a0a3a1a', 'john');
this.sendKeys('#app_L2b0a0a0a3b1a', 'john123');
this.click(x('//*[@id="app_L2b0a0a0a4a"]'),
  this.wait('5000',function(){
    this.capture('ctrlqpass.png');
  })
);
```

The above code neither trigger an error nor the success page. In all cases, casper capture the screenshot of the initial page. Any help much appreciated..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is an XML document with an attached stylesheet (XSL) which is used to transform the page into HTML or XHTML. This is done by most browsers automatically.

It seems that PhantomJS is compiled by default with XSLT processing being disabled. So, the stylesheet isn't processed and PhantomJS regards this as arbitrary data.

You can either compile PhantomJS with the needed option set or use SlimerJS as the engine for CasperJS. The used gecko engine does support XSLT transformation by default.

Another avenue might be to use [XSLTProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) that is included in JavaScript to transform the content yourself, but that is also not available in PhantomJS.

Comment: Note that SlimerJS can also be run [headlessly](http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/installation.html#having-a-headless-slimerjs) if you have xvfb.